# Aria2 excluir extensiones de archivos en txt

Tags: cmd

¿Existe alguna forma de excluir tipos de archivos en un listado txt? Como por ejemplo imágenes (jpg, png, gif, etc). ¿También sería posible excluir dominios?

El comando que estoy usando para descargar todas las URL de un fichero txt es:

```
$ aria2-1.33.1-win-32bit-build1\aria2c.exe -i C:\Users\tomi\Desktop\url
```

Comment: Entiendo que es en entorno Windows, luego puse la etiqueta [tag:cmd] en lugar de [tag:shell] que es para entorno Linux.

Comment: Si, perdón. Quizás la etiqueta shell no está bien. Pero Aria2 puede usarse en cmd/shell..

Comment: Si fuera en shell Bash, por ejemplo, se podría utilizar la expansión `*` y similar. Siendo como es algo en Windows, ya se trata de buscar cómo lo hacen allí.

Comment: Me podrías dar un ejemplo más claro? Te lo agradecería.

Comment: `ls -l *.!(txt)` te listará todos los elementos cuyo nombre no termina por `.txt` ([referencia](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/426091/40596)).